# Independent variables with Laplace distribution

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a task:
Take two-dimension series of independent random variables $(X_n,Y_n)$, where for each $n$ variables $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are also independent and they have Laplace distribution with density:
$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}e^{-|x|}$

Find $c$ such that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\right)^2}>c\sqrt{n}\right) = 0.05$$

Density function of $\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ is equal:
$g(x)=\frac{1}{2^n}e^{-n|x|}$.
I did in this way:
$$P\left(\sqrt{\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i\right)^2}>c\sqrt{n}\right)=P\left(2\cdot\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i\right)^2>c^2n\right)=P(\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i>\sqrt{\frac{c^2n}{2})}$$
And then I calculated integral, but it is wrong. 
Do you know how do it properly? 
Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Comment: Thank you, but I have some errors in the last line.

Comment: Adding two independent random variables is not the same as doubling one of them.

Comment: @John1357: You do indeed; you still have a pair of miniature parentheses there :-)

Comment: Do you know central limit theorem?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb E[X_i]=\mathbb E[Y_i]=0$ and $\text{Var}(X_i)=\text{Var}(Y_i)=1$, CLT implies
$$
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^n X_i }{ \sqrt{n} } \xrightarrow{\mathcal D} \mathcal N(0,1) 
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}{\sqrt{n}} \xrightarrow{\mathcal D} \mathcal N(0,1) 
$$
So 
$$
\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2 \xrightarrow{\mathcal D} \chi^2_1
$$
and the same for second square. The sequences are independent, so
$$
\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nX_i}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2+\left( \dfrac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}{\sqrt{n}} \right)^2 =\dfrac{\left(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)^2+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nY_i\right)^2}{n} \xrightarrow{\mathcal D} \chi^2_2 
$$
This is exponential distribution with expectation $2$. 
Use this to find $c$.